# Subscript out of Range for a function?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm relatively new to VBA.

I am receiving a "Subscript out of range" error while running the below code. The error occurs when attempting call values from the created functions, see lines 21 thru 24

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

```
Public Sub MtgLnYTM()

 Dim cpn As Single, maturity As Integer, price As Integer, mtgprice As Integer,    mort_price() As Double, yield_calc() As Double, calc_price As Integer
 Dim row As Integer


'asks user for Coupon rate
cpn = InputBox("Please enter the coupon rate of the security(in X.XX form)")
If -0.0001 < coupon < 25.0001 Then
Cells(1, 2).Value = cpn
End If

'asks user for number of years until maturity
maturity = InputBox("Please enter the periods until maturity")
If 179 < maturity < 361 Then
Cells(2, 2).Value = maturity
End If

'asks user for yield rate
mtgprice = InputBox("Please enter the Mortgage price per $100 principal value, in percent")
If 49.9999 < Yield < 200.0001 Then
Cells(3, 2).Value = mtgprice
End If

For row = 6 To 16
        Cells(row, 2).Value = mort_price(mtgprice, cpn, maturity)
        Cells(row, 1).Value = yield_calc(mtgprice, fderiv(mtgprice, cpn, maturity), mort_price(mtgprice, cpn, maturity))
Next row

Dim mychart As ChartObject
Dim mylo As Integer, myhi As Integer

mylo = -1 + WorksheetFunction.Min(Range("B6:B16"))
myhi = 1 + WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("B6:B16"))

Set mychart = Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects.Add _
    (Left:=300, Top:=25, Width:=400, Height:=300)

With mychart
    .Chart.ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    .Chart.HasTitle = True
    .Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Price of a " & maturity & " month mortgage loan with an annual coupon rate of " & cpn & "%"
    .Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A6:B16")
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = mylo
    .Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = myhi
    .Chart.Legend.Clear

End With


End Sub
```

Comment: You never initialize the `mort_price` and `yield_calc` arrays.

Comment: Also, constructs like `If -0.0001 < coupon < 25.0001 Then` are not doing what you think they are (and `coupon` isn't declared or initialized anywhere anyway).  See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5813/operators/20479/comparison-operators#t=20161026223525440529) from Documentation.

Answer (score -1):

By my count the lines '21 thru 24' are as follows:

If 49.9999 < Yield < 200.0001 Then

Cells(3, 2).Value = mtgprice

End If

---

Which seem fine.

1. If your functions mort_price, yield_calc or fderiv aren't declared properly you will get "Subscript out of range"
2. You will also get "Subscript out of range" if a worksheet named 'Sheet1' does not exist in your workbook already.

Comment: `If 49.9999 < Yield < 200.0001 Then` is ***not*** fine.  `49.9999 < Yield` will evaluate either to `True` (-1) or `False` (0), which will ***always*** be `< 200.0001`.  See [Comparison Operators](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/5813/operators/20479/comparison-operators#t=201610290313036822703) in Documentation.

Comment: True - they won't run as expected. But they will also not cause the error described.